Finding the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\prod_{i=1}^n\cos^{1/i}{(ix)}}{1-\prod_{i=1}^n \cos(ix)}$
I was wondering how I could evaluate the expression $L$ as given below.
$$\begin{equation}L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n\cos^{1/i}{(ix)}}{1-\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n \cos(ix)}.\end{equation}$$
I don't think either the Maclaurin series or L'Hopital's rule would immediately apply. Is there any form of transformation I can make to this limit? Thank you for the help.

$L=\frac3{2n+1}$

First, construct two auxiliary limits (also two important limts)
$$I_n=\lim\limits_{x\to0}
     \frac{1-\prod_{i=1}^n\cos^{1/i}{(ix)}}{x^2},\quad
J_n=\lim\limits_{x\to0}
     \frac{1-\prod_{i=1}^n \cos(ix)}{x^2},$$
then
$$I_1=\frac12,\quad I_{n}-I_{n-1}
   =\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\sqrt[^n\!]{\cos{nx}}}{x^2}
   =\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos{nx}}{n\cdot x^2}
   =\dfrac{n}{2},$$
so $$I_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k}{2}=\dfrac{n(n+1)}{4}.$$
Similarly,
$$J_1=1/2,\quad J_{n}-J_{n-1}
   =\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{1-\cos{nx}}{x^2}
   =\dfrac{n^2}{2}.$$
Thus $$J_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac{k^2}{2}=\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}.$$
Hence
$$L=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1-\displaystyle\prod_{i=1}^n\cos^{1/i}{(ix)}}{1-\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n \cos(ix)}
=\frac{I_n}{J_n}=\frac{3}{2n+1}.$$

Hint
MacLaurin works very well for this problem if you consider the products and take the logartihm.
Starting from the series of $\cos(x)$ around $x=0$
$$\log\big(\cos(ix)\big)=-\frac{i^2 x^2}{2}-\frac{i^4
   x^4}{12}-\frac{i^6
   x^6}{45}+O\left(x^8\right)$$ Compute
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \log\big(\cos(ix)\big)=A+O\left(x^8\right)$$ and exponentiate
Do the same for
$$\frac 1 i\log\big(\cos(ix)\big)$$ Compute the summation and exponentiate again.
At this point, you will have something simple.

It's coming something close to 0.014925 using Desmos :) (if n=100)

@Gwen. Not at all. The limit is a function of $n$ and  if $n\to \infty$, it will be $0$.

I don't understand. Can you please explain how you got $n\to \infty$. We are getting $x\to0$ from the question but how $n$? Thanks in advance

@Gwen. As I said $L$ is a function of $n$. Now, if you also take the limit of $L(n)$ you should get $0$.. Just try for $n=2,3,4$; I am sure that you will notice the pattern.

@Gwen. Id you used $n=100$, the result is $\frac 3{201}=0.0149254$ as you found it.

I see, thank you. I'm looking for a more elegant approach without the use of series expansions.

We have that for the numerator
$$1-\prod_{i=1}^n\cos^{1/i}{(ix)}=1-\prod_{i=1}^ne^{\frac{\log\left(\cos{(ix)}\right)}{i}}=1-e^{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\log\left(\cos{(ix)}\right)}{i} }=1-e^{-\frac{n(n+1)}4x^2+O(x^4)} =$$
$$=\frac{n(n+1)}4x^2+O(x^4)\tag 1$$
indeed $\cos(ix)=1-\frac{(ix)^2}2+O(x^4)$ and since $\log(1+x)=x +O(x^2)$ we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\log\left(\cos{(ix)}\right)}{i}=-\frac{x^2}2\sum_{i=1}^ni+O(x^4)=-\frac{n(n+1)}4x^2+O(x^4)$$
and for the denominator
$$1- \prod_{i=1}^n \cos(ix)=\frac{x^2}2\sum_{i=1}^ni^2+O(x^4)=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}x^2+O(x^4) \tag 2$$
therefore, using $(1)$ and $(2)$, the limit searched limit is
$$\frac{1-\prod_{i=1}^n\cos^{1/i}{(ix)}}{1- \prod_{i=1}^n \cos(ix)}=\frac{\frac{n(n+1)}4x^2+O(x^4)}{\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}x^2+O(x^4)}=\frac{3+O(x^2)}{2n+1+O(x^2)}\to \frac{3}{2n+1}$$
